# Embed a single wiki page in a javascript page (dynamic creation)

Tags: php, javascript, embed, wiki, html

Can we have a wiki page -e.g. in a tab-  (to collaboratively write and edit a text) inside a javascript page by a PHP server?

What I want is the following: consider you have a website (javascript, php) showing some information, and you want your page to consist of two tabs: one for the information display and one as a **single** wiki *page* to collaboratively write something about the information tab. As an alternative to the tab, we may use a link but I **don't want** the link to direct user to an external page or to another system (like a standalone complete wiki).

I haven't used wiki (as a programmer), if the answer to this question is positive, then I will start using it! So, please consider me as a total beginner. If you know something other than wiki which can support collaborative editing on a single page please let me know, there should be lighter techniques.

EDIT:
I want the page to be dynamically created, so having only one page is not useful, I have *n* information tabs which are created according to some data and I need *n* corresponding wiki pages (so, I can't create these pages manually and add them to my system).

Thanks

Comment: You could check out [wikimatrix.org](http://wikimatrix.org/) first. There is more than just MediaWiki. WikyBlog for example is pretty AJAXish. And there are all-Javascript Wiki implementations. Else try [WardsWiki:WikiEngines](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WikiEngines)

Comment: Thanks! I have a better understanding of available wikis now.. If a wiki is an all-javascript implementation, does it mean that I can embed one single wiki page in my own website?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm looking to embed a wiki within a site as well but I'm having trouble finding a good way to do it.

Comment: No, I gave up with it! I need only simple collaborative editing pages (the problem is having it dynamically created..), so I'm thinking of GoogleDocs API instead of wiki. As far as I have searched till now, GoogleDocs API also is not a perfect solution in my case, but I haven't looked deep enough yet..

Comment: Somebody posted an answer here (using www.dooWikis.com) and I was going to thank him and say that I have edited the question (saying that I forgot to mention that I want it to be dynamically created). I don't know why that answer is gone now! That was a good answer, actually perfect for my question ignoring my edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using a similar solution by simply using a IFRAME pointing to a external wiki URL. The URL depends on the item the user is currently working on.

Most Wiki systems allow you to open any inexistent URL/Wiki page and create the page with one click.

In our case we are using MoinMoin wiki, but I guess you could use almost every Wiki system out there.

Comment: that's it! thanks! Just I'm now looking for this: people can be logged in (and have accounts) into that wiki page if they are logged in to my system. I am looking at the documentation, but if you know the solution right away, that will be great! I'm also looking at MoinMoin or probably a few more wikis. I have a lot of time to do this!

Comment: In our case we are "always" logged in to the (completely private) Wiki itself so we don't need no special authentication mechanism since it's just a standard Wiki feature. FYI: although MoinMoin works great in this regard, it's WYSIWYG editor regularly messes up it's tables and spaces around bold or italic words (at least or version), so I would recommend looking at other systems.